# Sizeable Horizontal ItemsControl in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, itemscontrol

I want a Items Control which shows items in a horizontal alignment and it should stretch / size over the whole aviable horizontal space.
Currently I have 7 Columns, but it would be possible that the amount may be dynamic.

First of all I used a stackpanel as items like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

This works for the horizontal alignment requirement.
But, as the stackpanel does, it does not strecth. It always has the same size not regarding the aviable space of the device.

What Items.Panel should I use to achieve this?

Any advice?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a UniformGrid. There is [one](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c5#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/UniformGrid/UniformGrid.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit.